# FingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints() returns true with no fingerprints enrolled

Tags: android

The problem that I am facing is that on a few Android devices that have a fingerprint reader, the method `FingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()` returns true although there are no registered fingerprints on this device.
When trying to generate a key afterwards, this lead to crash as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one fingerprint 
must be enrolled to create keys requiring user authentication for every use

at android.security.keystore.KeymasterUtils.addUserAuthArgs(KeymasterUtils.java:115)                                                                                             at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:234)                                                                                              
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi$AES.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:53)                                                                                                   
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:189)...
```

Before checking if fingerprints are enrolled I check `FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()`because that was a source of problem earlier. Searching for a solution I have found some entries that note that this kind of behaviour was noticed in some Emulators, however no-one mentioned physical devices.

Note: The troubled devices are not at my disposal, but via logs I can confirm that the problem is recurring.

If someone had faced the same problem before I would greatly appreciate
any advice how this problem could be solved.

Comment: Same thing. I'm getting crash reports from Developer Console with the following: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.security.keystore.KeymasterUtils.addUserAuthArgs(KeymasterUtils.java:115)
  at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:272)
  at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(KeyGenerator.java:174) devices are mostly: OnePlus2 (OnePlus2) and Lenovo K5 Note and Acer Z110 (Z1)

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry no news yet. However, this question is starting to draw some attention, so probably we'll find a solution.

Comment: Did you guys find any fix for this?

Comment: @Mustansir no solution yet, thank you for your interest.

Comment: It has been 3 years... and not a single solution or suggestion! Woah 